# Web Share API (navigator.share) is crashing my android chrome browser if I share more than 1 file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigator

I am trying to share multiple image files from a react app using web share API (`navigator.share()`). Now the problem is if I am sharing more than 1 image file, my android chrome browser is crashing instantly.
I tried the same with my friends' devices (including IOS).
The result was out of 7 mobile devices, 4 failed to share the image file and their browser crashes immediately as the code reaches the line `navigator.share({files:files})`. No issue found on 2 android and 1 IOS device. Such a weird behaviour from the code.

On chrome web, I got this error. `DOMException: Failed to execute 'share' on 'Navigator': Must be handling a user gesture to perform a share request.`

I have added the code in codesandbox. The prodCode.js file has the code which I am using in my project. I have just changed the file names and nothing is different, but still if you want to check it, you can check. Also, if uncomment line 33 and comment line 34 to have 1 file in array, then it works for me on every device.
Here is the link for my codesandbox. [GO TO LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/web-share-api-trial4-rfgfss?file=/src/App.js)

I have tried `try catch` and other links from forums but nothing is working.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], where it says "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so — **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript/HTML/CSS.".

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. After clicking to share images Chrome Android got crashed. Firefox Android does not crash but is silent. 

I want to add more info here on my side so far.

As Chrome Android got crashed I see no error message from remote debugging.
But on Firefox Android, remote debugging found an error - `TypeError: Navigator.share: Passing files is currently not supported.`

The code used to work. 
And it is still working on Safari Mac Desktop, Safari iOS16 simulator, and Chrome iPadAir.

Comment: @Chaochana Thank you for replying back. I felt that I was the only one who is facing this issue. I tried adb logcat to find out the issue, but no luck. If you know about a workaround, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: @paarthbajaj unsure how it goes from your side. I gave up since then until I recently pick it up again. It's good now, I can share multiple photos from gallery of my SaaS https://www.pixid.app except one more issue - if photo is large and too many, share panel is just silent. Nothing show up.